# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file after installing Node.js - Windows

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I was looking for this topic but none of the founded solutions works for me.
I'm working on a Laptop with Windows 10 OS, where I do not have admin rights.
I'm trying to run my Angular + NodeJS app on this machine after cloning the repository from GitHub.
After installing Node.js from the official site (admin put his credentials to do that) I can not run 'npm' command anywhere (cmd or VS Code terminal). Always received same error:

```
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

In "Control Panel" I can see that Node.js is installed.
Any help will be useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the node command to your path (i. e. C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd).
If you are not able to add something to the path, open your command line, go to the node folder and start npm.cmd from there.

Answer (score 1):

add ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\ in your environment path